# Stateflow is not working with Matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink, stateflow

I cannot run state flow diagram from Matlab. I am using Matlab 2013b. Whenever I try to run it it gives a warning:

> Warning: The model 'xyz' does not have continuous states, hence
>   Simulink is using the solver'FixedStepDiscrete' instead of solver
>   'ode4'. You can disable this diagnostic by explicitly specifying a
>   discrete solver in the solver tab of the Configuration Parameters
>   dialog, or by setting the 'Automatic solver parameter selection'
>   diagnostic to 'none' in the Diagnostics tab of the Configuration
>   Parameters dialog

However I have modified the above mentioned two requirement from configuration setup. But it is still showing problem. Do I need to set up some additional software to fix this problem?

Comment: Could you post the diagram or give us a glimpse of how it is, and what do you expect it to do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a warning, not an error message, your model will run just fine as is. If you want to get rid of the message, change the solver in the model to `FixedStepDiscrete` instead of `ode4` and it will go away, but it won't change anything in the actual running of the model.

Comment: But it is not generating any graph.